# Is backup service automacially region-redundant?

Tags: azure-backup-vault

I'm learning about Azure redundancy polices, which consists of locally redundant storage, zone redundant storage and region redundant storage.
However when I tried to set up automatic back up service on my virtual machine, it doesn't give me options to choose from. Is backing up always done in a region redundant way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Azure Backup does not have to use geo-redundancy (GRS) - you could configure a different redundancy option. However, by default it is indeed using GRS.

Please see the Azure Backup Architecture Overview for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-architecture

Specifically, the 'Where is data backed up?' section outlines the redundancy options.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this link. Is creating a snapshot of a data disk a simpler solution than backing up the entire virtual machine? If all I need is on the data disk. Thanks.